# replace every value with one of another vector - dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe with two columns, made like this:

```
> co_purchase
    Source Target
1        0      1
2        0      2
3        0      3
4        0      4
5        0      5
6        1      0
7        1      2
8        1      4
9        1      5
10       1     15
```

I want to change each value with the character one in position value+1 of another vector. I have tried this, even if it would replace just one column if it would work:

```
co_purchase %>% 
  mutate(Source = recode(Source, products$group[Source + 1]))
```

But this results in most of NA's, with the following error:

```
Warning message:
Problem with `mutate()` column `Source`.
i `Source = recode(...)`.
i Unreplaced values treated as NA as .x is not compatible. Please specify replacements exhaustively or supply .default
```

The `group` vector, is made like this:

```
 [1] NA      "Book"  "Book"  "Book"  "Book"  "Book"  "Book"  "Music" "Book"  "Book"  "Book"  "Book"  "Book"  "Book"  "Music"
```

So, the desired output for would be the following:

```
> co_purchase
      Source     Target
1        NA      "Book"
2        NA      "Book"
3        NA      "Book"
4        NA      "Book"
5        NA      "Book"
6      "Book"      NA
7      "Book"    "Book"
8      "Book"    "Book"
9      "Book"    "Book"
10     "Book"    "Music"
```

Comment: There's no column `group`. Can you post expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need `recode`. Try this -

```
library(dplyr)
co_purchase %>% mutate(Source = products$group[Source + 1])
```

Or in base R -

```
co_purchase$Source <- products$group[co_purchase$Source + 1]
```

---

For multiple columns use `across` -

```
co_purchase %>% mutate(across(.fns = ~products$group[. + 1]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way to do both columns at once?

Comment: @Maurinho Use `across` for that. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

We can just use `base R` for this

```
co_purchase$Source <- with(products, group[co_purchase$Source + 1])
```

---

Or in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(co_purchase)[, Source := products$group[Source + 1]]
```